# Coger ciertas partes de un string PHP

Tags: php

Tengo este string:

```
"a:11: i:0;s:3:"191";i:1;s:3:"256";i:2;s:3:"247";i:3;s:3:"244";i:4;s:3:"257";i:5;s:3:"250";i:6;s:3:"253";i:7;s:3:"258";i:8;s:3:"261";i:9;s:3:"259";i:10;s:3:"542";}
```

Quiero coger los números que están entre comillas ex: **"191"**

He intentado con explode, pero corta por sitios donde no me sirve.
Ni split, hasta strpos, pero me devuelve la posición de la primera coincidencia.

Necesitaría algo como lo que este entre **"%"**

Comment: Has probado con una [Expresión Regular](https://regexr.com/)?

Comment: @NicolasOñate No lo había contemplado, me pongo a mirarlo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Prueba esto:

```
$cadena = 'a:11: i:0;s:3:"191";i:1;s:3:"256";i:2;s:3:"247";i:3;s:3:"244";i:4;s:3:"257";i:5;s:3:"250";i:6;s:3:"253";i:7;s:3:"258";i:8;s:3:"261";i:9;s:3:"259";i:10;s:3:"542"';
preg_match_all('/"(.*?)"/', $cadena, $m);
print_r($m[1]);
```

Usando esta expresión regular debería devolverte un array con los números entrecomillados.

Comment: Perfección, devuelvo todo lo que busco y genial

Answer (score 3):

El formato de esa cadena que tienes es un `serialize` de php. Es decir, un array serializado, pero en lugar de utilizar json, se ha utilizado la funcion serialize de php. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Lo que debes hacer es des-serializarlo:

```
$cadena= '"a:11: i:0;s:3:"191";i:1;s:3:"256";i:2;s:3:"247";i:3;s:3:"244";i:4;s:3:"257";i:5;s:3:"250";i:6;s:3:"253";i:7;s:3:"258";i:8;s:3:"261";i:9;s:3:"259";i:10;s:3:"542";}';
$cadena_array = unserialize($cadena);
```

Con esto, tendras en $cadena_array un array de php, al que puedes acceder con los indices correspondientes del array.

Comment: Es cierto, también me sirve